# Nginx upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream form Node js rocky proxy

Tags: node.js, nginx, proxy

I have nginx and one node server which works as proxy between java backend servers.
my nginx config

```
server {
listen 80;

server_name peoplehum.dev www.peoplehum.dev;
#rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;
charset utf-8;
keepalive_requests 100;
keepalive_timeout 100s;
gzip on;
gzip_http_version 1.1;
gzip_vary on;
gzip_comp_level 6;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_buffers 16 8k;
gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)";
client_max_body_size 16M;

#include /etc/nginx/proxy_header.conf;
#include /etc/nginx/proxy_buffer.conf;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header HOST $host;

#X-Forwarded-Proto header gives the proxied server information about the schema of the original client request (whether it was an http or an https request).
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

#The X-Real-IP is set to the IP address of the client so that the proxy can correctly make decisions or log based on this information.
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

#The X-Forwarded-For header is a list containing the IP addresses of every server the client has been proxied through up to this point.
#In the example above, we set this to the $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for variable.
#This variable takes the value of the original X-Forwarded-For header retrieved from the client and adds the Nginx server's IP address to the end.
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

here, when i send big body request to nginx to my node proxy server it gives upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream.

I am using rocky proxy--> https://github.com/h2non/rocky on node js for proxy.
I have searched alot and tried most of other question answers related this but nothing worked out.

Answer (score 0):

After so much digging into this problem finally i got problem root cause.I was decorating request with some data using this function [here](https://github.com/h2non/rocky#routeuseforwardmiddleware) and for doing so
I was using a function which was async call to Redis for getting some data and i wanted that to be sync for doing so i used this package [deasync](https://github.com/abbr/deasync).
it worked for small files or data but when when it comes to more data or large file don't know it starts failing.

**as learning what i suggest is use native promises or use any other package which is actually built on promises or use** [async await](https://blog.risingstack.com/mastering-async-await-in-nodejs/).